# Select all on dojo checkbox group

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I currently have a dojo checkbox group (dijit.form.CheckBox with names in the form "some_name[]")  It works exactly as desired however I need to add a select all button/link, preferably not another checkbox (this shouldn't be necessary given the functionality will be implemented in js).

Is the a "dojo" way to do this as using standard js seems to get the elements fine but setting element.checked=true has no effect.  For the purposes of testing, I've disabled the dijit.form.CheckBox (so I have regular bog standard checkboxes) and I am able to mark all the boxes checked with the code that is failing when dojo'ified.

I'm running dojo 1.5 if that makes any difference

UPDATE:

OK, it seems to be setting the checkbox to be checked/unchecked but not re-rendering the dojo widget.  I'm also being told that the checkboxes don't have any of the method I would expect them to have as dijit.form.CheckBox objects (like the set() method).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I found out what the problem was.  I was doing dojo.query() to get the checkbox group dom nodes.  This however doesn't return the dijit widget.  To get those I had to do:

```
nodes = dojo.query('[name=\"checkbox_group[]\"]'); 
dojo.forEach(nodes,function(node)   
  {dijit.getEnclosingWidget(node).set("checked",true);});
```

By manipulating the widget it visually updates correctly.  Also, I wasn't aware that the checkbox input element isn't the widget itself so `dijit.byNode(node)` returns undefined because the checkbox node doesn't match any of the initialised dijit widgets.

Answer (score 0):

We do this something like show below. This is trimmed down from a lot of other things that get hooked up as handlers in an "addHandlers" function that gets called when the page is loaded.

The `selectall` and `clearall` are the links that we're hooking up to.

```
var selectall = dojo.byId('selectall');
var clearall  = dojo.byId('clearall');

var checklist = getCheckboxList(); // Magic happens here (1)

dojo.connect(selectall, "onclick",
    function(evt) {
        allClick(evt, checklist, true);
    }
);

dojo.connect(clearall, "onclick",
    function(evt) {
        allClick(evt, checklist, false);
    }
);
```

(1) We get a list of the checkboxes that will be affected based on some ugly criteria, and we use the list for more than this check/clear-all -- you could probably do something much simpler to get yours.

The "allClick" function just checks or unchecks the list of things you pass it

```
function allClick(evt, list, checkstate)
{
    dojo.forEach(list,
        function(el, idx, ary) {
            el.checked = checkstate;
        }
    );
    evt.preventDefault(); // keep the link from firing
}
```

Comment: This is what I've been doing.  The problem is dojo seems to be overriding e1.checked = true;

Comment: I found the answer below.  Sorry I couldn't be clearer in the original question, I'm still finding my way around dojo and frequently don't know what piece of the puzzle I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking at this for the answer, and there is now (4 years later) another way to do this:

```
var checkboxes = registry.findWidgets(dom.byId('checkGroupWrapper'));

checkboxes.forEach(function (checkboxWidg) {
    checkboxWidg.set('checked', true);
});
```

See [this documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/registry.html#finding-all-widgets-underneath-a-dom-node).